# populating a dropdown based on selection of another dropdown value not accepting numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need to write a code where i need to populate a dropdown based on the selection of another dropdown where in need to give values of dropdown as numeric value, but *script.js* not accepting any numeric value instead its  treating it as a decimal value..Am quite new to this concept please help me to resolve this issue, thank you

**data.json**

```
{
  "1": "coke,pepsi",
  "2":"chips,biscuit"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div class="form-group">
         <select id="json-one" class="form-control">  
           <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>  
           <option value="1">Beverages</option>  
           <option value="2">Snacks</option>  
         </select>  
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
               <select id="json-two" class="form-control">  
                 <option>Please choose from above</option>  
               </select>  
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
     $(function() {
$("#json-one").change(function() {

                var $dropdown = $(this);

                $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {


                    var key = $dropdown.val();
                    var vals = [];

                    switch(key) {
                        case 'beverages':
                            vals = data['1'].split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'snacks':
                            vals = data['2'].split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'base':
                            vals = ['Please choose from above'];
                    }

                    var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                    $jsontwo.empty();
                    $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                        $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                    });

                });
            });



 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`bracket-notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to access the data from `response`

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

Another issue is your `option` value is `0 or 1` but in `switch`, you are testing it with case `Beverages` and `Snacks`, Change it with `0` and `1`

```js
$("#json-one").change(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  var data = {
    "1": "coke,pepsi",
    "2": "chips,biscuit"
  };
  var key = $dropdown.val();
  var vals = [];
  switch (key) {
    case '1':
      vals = data['1'].split(",");
      break;
    case '2':
      vals = data['2'].split(",");
      break;
    case 'base':
      vals = ['Please choose from above'];
  }
  var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
  $jsontwo.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="json-one" class="form-control">
    <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Beverages</option>
    <option value="2">Snacks</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="json-two" class="form-control">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Simplified code:**

```js
$("#json-one").change(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  var data = {
    "1": "coke,pepsi",
    "2": "chips,biscuit"
  };
  var key = $dropdown.val();
  var vals = data[key] ? data[key].split(",") : ['Please choose from above'];
  var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
  $jsontwo.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="json-one" class="form-control">
    <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Beverages</option>
    <option value="2">Snacks</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="json-two" class="form-control">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sir i have updated my .js code can through some light on to it.!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer..!!